# Auth0 - Customizing SAML Assertions not working

Tags: saml, auth0

I'm using Auth0 as an idP, my Service Provider requires that i add a custom attribute in the assertion.

I've tried doing this on the Dashboard. ***Dashboard > Applications > Applications -> AddOns.*** Following this article. https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/protocols/saml/saml-configuration/customize-saml-assertions

I've added `my_custom_attr` in the `mapping` object, screenshot below.

However when i 'Debug', my custom attribute isn't showing in the **assertion xml** and my Service Provider isn't receiving the custom attribute. They're only receiving the default attributes. *email, nickname* etc

[image: Mapping SAML assertion]

Answer (score 0):

When using Auth0 as a SAML identity provider, you can customize the outgoing claims using mapping. Consider you have the user profile that looks like this:

RAW JSON

```
{
    "user_id": "auth0|qwer-1234-zxcv-0987",
    "email": "john.doe@example.com"
    "picture": "https://placeholder.img/user",
    "name": "John Doe"
}
```

If you need the `picture` attribute to be in the outgoing claims, you would do a mapping like this:

```
"mappings": {
    "picture": "http://schemas.auth0.com/picture"
}
```

Note that the each property name on the left side represents a property in the Auth0 profile. Each "value" on the right side is the name for the resulting SAML attribute in the assertion.

If you don't have a `my_custom_attr` property in the user profile, this mapping won't work. The workaround is to use an Auth0 Rule to add that value during the user log in time. You can read more about it [here](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/protocols/saml/saml-configuration/customize-saml-assertions#use-rules).

Here's an example.

```
function customizeMappings(user, context, callback) {
    // we are altering the user profile
    user.my_custom_attr = "My Custom Attribute";

    context.samlConfiguration.mappings = {
        "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/color": "my_custom_attr"
    };

    callback(null, user, context);
}
```

Note that using `context.samlConfiguration.mappings` in a Rule will override the configuration you've set in your SAML add-on. Therefore, all the mappings you set in the add-on will be lost if you're using a Rule to customize the SAML assertions.